# Changing my code/text editor in mac terminal

Tags: git, macos, text-editor, git-config

I am going through a course for version control basics and I cannot make git commits using the code editor I configured "atom".

So in order to process commits through my code editor I would like to switch editors but my config command will not configure sublime text.

This is what happens when I try to process the config with quotes

```
$ git config --global core.editor "subl -n -w"
warning: core.editor has multiple values
error: cannot overwrite multiple values with a single value
       Use a regexp, --add or --replace-all to change core.editor.
```

When I input the config command without quotes it appears to go through but it is still unusable.

```
$ git config --global core.editor subl -n -w
usage: git config [<options>]

Config file location
    --global              use global config file
    --system              use system config file
    --local               use repository config file
    -f, --file <file>     use given config file
    --blob <blob-id>      read config from given blob object

Action
    --get                 get value: name [value-regex]
    --get-all             get all values: key [value-regex]
    --get-regexp          get values for regexp: name-regex [value-regex]
    --get-urlmatch        get value specific for the URL: section[.var] URL
    --replace-all         replace all matching variables: name value [value_regex]
    --add                 add a new variable: name value
    --unset               remove a variable: name [value-regex]
    --unset-all           remove all matches: name [value-regex]
    --rename-section      rename section: old-name new-name
    --remove-section      remove a section: name
    -l, --list            list all
    -e, --edit            open an editor
    --get-color           find the color configured: slot [default]
    --get-colorbool       find the color setting: slot [stdout-is-tty]

Type
    --bool                value is "true" or "false"
    --int                 value is decimal number
    --bool-or-int         value is --bool or --int
    --path                value is a path (file or directory name)
    --expiry-date         value is an expiry date

Other
    -z, --null            terminate values with NUL byte
    --name-only           show variable names only
    --includes            respect include directives on lookup
    --show-origin         show origin of config (file, standard input, blob, command line)
```

When I try to do a commit I get this result back.

```
$ git commit
hint: Waiting for your editor to close the file... subl -n -w: subl: command not found
error: There was a problem with the editor 'subl -n -w'.
Please supply the message using either -m or -F option.
```

This is the status I get when I run `git var -l`.

```
credential.helper=osxkeychain
filter.lfs.smudge=git-lfs smudge -- %f
filter.lfs.process=git-lfs filter-process
filter.lfs.required=true
filter.lfs.clean=git-lfs clean -- %f
user.name=xxxx xxxxxxxxxx
user.email=xxxxxxxxxx@yahoo.com
core.editor=c48875ba-b535-4644-ba4d-1a8d011d4c51
core.editor=atom
core.editor=atom
core.editor=atom
core.editor=atom
core.editor=atom
core.editor=atom
core.editor=atom
core.editor=atom
core.editor=atom
cor.editor=subl -n -w
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.ignorecase=true
core.precomposeunicode=true
core.editor=subl -n -w
GIT_COMMITTER_IDENT=xxxx xxxxxxxxxx <xxxxxxxxxx@yahoo.com> 1573775118 -0500
GIT_AUTHOR_IDENT=xxxx xxxxxxxxxx <xxxxxxxxxx@yahoo.com> 1573775118 -0500
GIT_EDITOR=subl -n -w
GIT_PAGER=less
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fundamental problem is the many repeated settings for `core.editor`.  The error message you got tells you one way to fix it:

```
error: cannot overwrite multiple values with a single value
   Use a regexp, --add or --replace-all to change core.editor.
```

so adding the `--replace-all` option to your existing command-line command should suffice.

---

If you don't like that, though, there are a lot more options.

If you're confident that your chosen editor produces good-and-proper (for Git) plain-text files—for Git, this means files with no rich-text encoding, in UTF-8, without byte-order marks, and with newlines terminating each line—you can just run your editor directly on your global configuration file:

```
vim $HOME/.gitconfig
```

for instance, if your editor is `vim` and the global config file is in the usual place (some installations use a less-usual location).  You can also run:

```
git config --global --edit
```

to run your currently-chosen editor on the file, but of course that requires that your currently-chosen editor be the editor you want. :-)  There's one more trick here:

```
git -c core.editor=some-editor-of-choice --global --edit
```

The `-c` option lets you override any setting you like, for the duration of this one single command.  So this tells Git: *Using the editor I chose for this one command, invoke this temporarily-chosen `core.editor` on my global config file.*

If you don't like any of those options, you can use:

```
git config --global --unset-all core.editor
```

to remove *every* `core.editor` setting, after which you have none, after which one `git config` should allow you to set one.

Note that `git config --global what.ever value` will replace the existing `what.ever` setting by default.  It's not clear how you to into the situation you are in, but `git config --global --add what.ever another-value` would *add* an additional `what.ever=another-value`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the useful info.

Comment: Unfortunately the code [git config --global core.editor subl -n -w --replace-all] did not get the desired results. Is there an issue with my formatting?

Comment: You will need the quotes you used originally, i.e., `git config --global --replace-all core.editor "subl -n -w"`. You got that big `usage` message when you gave `git config` something it didn't understand. The `--replace-all` *may* be able to go at the end, but it's best in general to put options and their arguments first, then the name-and-value part.

Comment: I got all of that to work but git commit still wont function with my code editor. Should I post a second question or is this an easy fix?                                           
    $ git commit
    hint: Waiting for your editor to close the file... subl -n -w: subl: command not 
    found
    error: There was a problem with the editor 'subl -n -w'.
    Please supply the message using either -m or -F option.

Comment: The *command not found* issue means that Git is unable to find a command named `subl` in `$PATH`. Where is your editor installed? Is that directory on the (exported) `$PATH`?

Comment: It is installed to applications, I don't know about $PATH.

Comment: `applications` is not a path - paths are things like `/usr/local/bin`, `/Users/<name>/scripts`, and so on, and ones in `$PATH` should start with a leading slash in general. Git needs to be able to run the editor using a MacOS `exec` system call. Apps (wherever they are installed) aren't directly exec-able but they have a binary in some subdirectory that is. For instance, my Firefox's binary is actually `/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin` so if I wanted to be able to start it via `exec` I would have to put `/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS` into `$PATH`.

Comment: You'll want to read up on how to configure your shell (the method varies from one shell / CLI to another, this stuff about `$PATH` is relatively common but tcsh uses `path` rather than `PATH`, for instance).

Comment: So far I have not been able to find any articles going over how to move my editor to $PATH. I don't suppose you have some code or an article I could look over to accomplish this do you?

Comment: You might not want to *move* it. I know nothing about Sublime and its specific usage, but in general, with big window-based thingies like this, what you want is a Unix utility program that has two to four phases: (1) prepare a work area if needed (2) submit a request to the big window-y GUI or whatever the hell it is (3) wait for it to deliver a result, perhaps in the work-area (4) massage that result if/as needed to behave in the way a Unix utility generally behaves and to deliver the result to stdout, or however it's supposed to work.

Comment: For file-editors specifically, the way the utility should work is: edit the file in-place, and exit 0 if the editing was successful and nonzero if something went wrong. So a "wait for the file to be edited" utility program would simply send the name of the file to the (already running) app, then wait for the app to signal "done editing and I've succeeded/failed: you should now return the appropriate exit status". It sounds like `subl -n -w` *is* this utility program.

Comment: **IF** all of the preceding is correct—and remember, I have to guess—then `subl` *is* the utility program, already written to behave well. It probably lives in some directory of "binaries that we supplied for your OS, so that your OS can use this app". You then simply need to put the *path* to this directory-full-of-programs into your `PATH` setting, in `~/.profile` or `~/.bashrc` or `~/.tcshrc` or whatever configuration file is used by whatever command line shell you use.

Comment: I am running Mac OS. I'm a little lost as far as your last comments go.  I'm not sure what you mean by phases. I imagine you mean creating a file, moving it to the staging index, and then committing it. I have not seen window-y or GUI before. I also don't know what exit-0 means. Also, I don't know what you mean putting the path of this directory in ~/.profile.

Comment: Also now for some reason unset-all is no longer able to wipe my settings.

Comment: "phase" is ordinary English: https://www.dictionary.com/browse/phase. The issue here is that (I assume) the *app* runs all the time (like, e.g., Firefox or Safari—it's just out there running all the time). Git doesn't run all the time. You run `git commit` and Git starts running. Git creates a file in which the commit message should go. Git then runs another command, and waits for it to signal that it is done. That command signals that it is done by exiting (this is an OS-level concept).

Comment: (I'm afraid that you need to read several books on Unix or Linux or MacOS and the use of its command-line to get started, at this point.)